# How can I compile this program in C with Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10s_u11wos_24a SPARC

Tags: c, solaris, sparc

Hello everyone Im triying to compile a C program correctly, but when I run the program throw the Error Ivalid Argument.

Im tried to put the architecture type like -xarch=sparc or -m64 but nothing

```
bash-3.2$ cc -c Prueba.c -o Prueba.o -xarch=sparc
bash-3.2$ chmod 777 Prueba.o
bash-3.2$ ./Prueba.o
bash: ./Prueba.o: Invalid argument
bash-3.2$ cat /etc/release
                   Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10s_u11wos_24a SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 17 January 2013
```

Comment: Um… you passed `-c`, so you got an object file instead of an executable?

Comment: You are building an object file without linking it (this is the effect of the `-c` option).  The result is not executable.

Comment: You don't run Object files (`.o`).  You run executable files.   Omit the `-o Prueba.o`, and you should get a `a.out` file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compiled a C file to an object module rather than compiling and linking with the C run-time and library to create a loadable executable.

You need something more like:

```
cc -o Prueba Prueba.c
chmod 777 Prueba
./Prueba
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, with that correction it works, now i understand the reason and my error.